# VSTS work items list through REST API

Tags: rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

How can I get a list of work items from VSTS using the REST API?

According to the [documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items), the `ids` parameter is optional, but when I omit it I get a `404` error.
If I add the `ids` parameter, I can get the items.

Failing request:
`GET https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?api-version=1.0`

Succeeding request:
`GET https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=252&api-version=1.0`

Authentication is the same for both.

The complete problem to solve is: **get all features in a specific VSTS project**

Comment: Have you solved this by any chance?

Comment: No, couldn't solve it yet

Comment: @fra could you please tell me how you have implemented the authentication? How do you get the token and how you send the token with the api for getting the workitems? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is to use **WIQL** part of the API, not the Work Item one.
For example to get a flat list of Work Items of some type use this:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql#a-flat-query

Example in PowerShell (shows all User Stories in Closed state):

```bsh
    # using env vars passed from VSTS build
    $collectionuri = $Env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI
    $token = $Env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN # need to configure build to allow passing OAuth tokens

    $basicAuth = "{0}:{1}"-f "ivan-the-terrible", $token
    $basicAuth = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($basicAuth)
    $basicAuth = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($basicAuth)
    $headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}"-f $basicAuth)}

    $WorkItemType = 'User Story'

    $url = $collectionuri + 'DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0'

    $WIQL_query = "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = '" + $WorkItemType + "' AND [State] = 'Closed' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"
    $body = @{ query = $WIQL_query }
    $bodyJson=@($body) | ConvertTo-Json

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -headers $headers -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $bodyJson

    $workitems = $response.workItems

    Write-Host "Found" $workitems.Count "work items of type:" $WorkItemType
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a similar solution that I wrote in C# to return a list of all work items of type Ticket. I was able to build this result utilizing the sample provided in the accepted answer and looking at the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql)

```
public QueryResult GetTickets()
{
    try
    {
        var token = "****";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(
                    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                        string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", token))));

            var query = "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Ticket' AND [State] <> 'Closed' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate]";                    
            var content = new StringContent("{ \"query\": \"" + query + "\" }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var url = "https://{account}.visualstudio.com/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=4.1";

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, content).Result)
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueryResult>(responseBody);

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }            
}
```