# How to get done/completed backlog items from Azure Dev Ops rest api?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

'Backlogs - Get Backlog Level Work Items' rest api seems to only return "open" work items, excluding done/completed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/backlogs/get%20backlog%20level%20work%20items?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

I don't see any additional parameter mentioned in the docs to return everything, so how to get completed items for a project/team/backlog combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get done/completed backlog items from Azure Dev Ops rest api?

You could not get done/completed backlog items. That because a product backlog represents your **project plan**, the roadmap for what **your team plans to deliver**. So, the done/completed backlog items will not be list in the Azure DevOps. If you change the state of any work item to `closed` on the backlog, backlog will remove that work item from backlog:

[image]

To get those done/completed work items, you could WIQL part of the API.

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034029/vsts-work-items-list-through-rest-api) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Even tough I marked this as answer, I'm struggling to get to the exact result with wiql, so I posted a follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688528/how-to-get-work-items-for-a-specific-team-with-wiql