# How to get work items for a specific team with wiql?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, wiql

I'm trying to get work items in any state for a specific PROJECT and TEAM with dev ops rest api.
As confirmed in [my old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54677361/how-to-get-done-completed-backlog-items-from-azure-dev-ops-rest-api), the backlog work item api won't do, because it doesn't return 'done' items.

What's the best way to do that with wiql?

I have issues in particular with filtering for a specific team.
The web interface leads to a query with the @TeamAreas macro but I can't figure out how to translate it to wiql, as Visual Studio 2017 says that "the syntax of the query is not supported".

Is there a way to translate the @TeamAreas macro, or is there a quick way to retrieve all the areas for a specific team?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no team field for work items. You need to get all team areas from team values: [Teamfieldvalues - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/teamfieldvalues/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0). This is my example with c# [Manage Team Settings](https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2018/12/29/azure-devops-services-rest-api-10-manage-team-settings/).

Then you may use this list in wiql.